# Should not "passive-voice" and "passive" be merged?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-cleaning

There are 46 questions using [passive](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/passive) and more than 300 questions using [passive-voice](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/passive-voice).

Should not the tags be merged? I would make [passive-voice](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/passive-voice) the main tags, and [passive](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/passive) its synonym.

Comment: Related discussion: http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/q/2478/9161

Comment: Also related: [Help with new “passive” tag](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/3251/help-with-new-passive-tag)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, I agree.  There's no reason to maintain these as separate tags.  They both clearly refer to the passive voice, and there is no distinction in how the tags are used.

I've gone ahead and merged [passive](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/passive) into [passive-voice](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/passive-voice), just as you've suggested.